# pandas python how to count the number of records or rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

Obviously new to Pandas. How can i simply count the number of records in a dataframe.

I would have thought some thing as simple as this would do it and i can't seem to even find the answer in searches...probably because it is too simple.

```
cnt = df.count
print cnt
```

the above code actually just prints the whole df

Comment: Ok it was simple. the len(dataframe) was the easy answer.

    print len(df3)

Comment: That works... just as an fyi it looks like you're leaving off the `()`, so when you call `cnt = df.count` you're actually setting `cnt` equal to a method of the dataframe, not the result of that method.  Try `cnt = df.count(); print cnt` to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ah. thanks tshauck, I guess that was actually what i was trying to do. The result to that test actually printed the count for each field i.e.Field1 = 10 and next line Field2 = 10. I guess you could also apply the count to one particular Field?

Comment: Sure - I answered your question about one field below so I could go into more detail.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Regards to your question... counting one Field?  I decided to make it a question, but I hope it helps...

Say I have the following DataFrame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (5, 2)), columns=["A", "B"])
```

You could count a single column by

```
df.A.count()
#or
df['A'].count()
```

both evaluate to 5.

The cool thing (or one of many w.r.t. `pandas`) is that if you have `NA` values, count takes that into consideration.

So if I did

```
df['A'][1::2] = np.NAN
df.count()
```

The result would be

```
 A    3
 B    5
```

Answer (score 51):

To get the number of rows in a dataframe use:

```
df.shape[0]
```

(and `df.shape[1]` to get the number of columns).

As an alternative you can use

```
len(df)
```

or

```
len(df.index)
```

(and `len(df.columns)` for the columns)

`shape` is more versatile and more convenient than `len()`, especially for interactive work (just needs to be added at the end), but `len` is a bit faster (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15943975/2314737)).

**To avoid**: [`count()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) because it returns *the number of non-NA/null observations over requested axis*

**`len(df.index)` is faster**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape(8, 3),columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['A'][5]=np.nan
df
# Out:
#     A   B   C
# 0   0   1   2
# 1   3   4   5
# 2   6   7   8
# 3   9  10  11
# 4  12  13  14
# 5 NaN  16  17
# 6  18  19  20
# 7  21  22  23

%timeit df.shape[0]
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.22 µs per loop

%timeit len(df)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.26 µs per loop

%timeit len(df.index)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 µs per loop
```

**`df.__len__`  is just a call to `len(df.index)`**

```
import inspect 
print(inspect.getsource(pd.DataFrame.__len__))
# Out:
#     def __len__(self):
#         """Returns length of info axis, but here we use the index """
#         return len(self.index)
```

**Why you should not use `count()`**

```
df.count()
# Out:
# A    7
# B    8
# C    8
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply, **row_num =  df.shape[0]**   # gives number of rows, here's the example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

In [322]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2), columns=["col_1", "col_2"])

In [323]: df
Out[323]: 
      col_1     col_2
0 -0.894268  1.309041
1 -0.120667 -0.241292
2  0.076168 -1.071099
3  1.387217  0.622877
4 -0.488452  0.317882

In [324]: df.shape
Out[324]: (5, 2)

In [325]: df.shape[0]   ## Gives no. of rows/records
Out[325]: 5

In [326]: df.shape[1]   ## Gives no. of columns
Out[326]: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The Nan example above misses one piece, which makes it less generic. To do this more "generically" use `df['column_name'].value_counts()`
This will give you the counts of each value in that column.

```
d=['A','A','A','B','C','C'," " ," "," "," "," ","-1"] # for simplicity

df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df.columns=["col1"]
df["col1"].value_counts() 
      5
A     3
C     2
-1    1
B     1
dtype: int64
"""len(df) give you 12, so we know the rest must be Nan's of some form, while also having a peek into other invalid entries, especially when you might want to ignore them like -1, 0 , "", also"""
```

Comment: and if NaNs are wanted use: df["col1"].value_counts(dropna=False)

Answer (score 0):

Simple method to get the records count:

```
df.count()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used pandas library for this. Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd


name_of_file =  "test.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(name_of_file)

required_colum_name = "Post test Number"

print(len(data[required_colum_name]))
# this also works -> data["Post test Number"].count()
```