# How to count excel row number for certain column with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to count row number for certain column with pandas.
I have DataFrame like this:

```
   A    B    C
0  1    a    a
1  2    b    b
2  3    c    c
3  4  NaN  NaN
4  5  NaN  NaN
5  6  NaN  NaN
6  7  NaN  NaN
7  8  NaN  NaN
8  9  NaN  NaN
```

I want to count number of rows in column B, my code looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheetname="test", index_col="1")
print(len(df))
print(df)
```

But regardless of what `index_col` i will put it always return the row number of longest column.

What should i change in the code to get the number o rows for column B but without empty rows?

Comment: `df.B.count()`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468878/pandas-python-how-to-count-the-number-of-records-or-rows-in-a-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

By using `last_valid_index`

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.last_valid_index()).add(1)
Out[440]: 
A    9
B    3
C    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: But `df.count()` is the best ;)

Comment: @jezrael yes. you are right ~ :)

Comment: @Bharathshetty which answer? Sry...

Comment: @Bharathshetty nope, I have been use this for a well ...