# Add len of two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, addition

I have two DataFrames `df1` and `df2`.

I want to see what the length of both is added up.

But it seems I can't do `len(df1) + len(df2)`.

Is there a quick way to do this (without joining them)?

Comment: Why can you not? If I do it it works fine.

Comment: Hm - maybe something is off with my index - let me try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fastest is sum [lengths of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15943975/2901002):

```
len(df1.index) + len(df2.index)
```

But is is same like your solution:

```
len(df1) + len(df2)
```

Comment: the index one works for me - I don't know why the one without index didn't' than kyou

Answer (score 1):

By using `shape`

```
df1.shape[0]+df2.shape[0]
```