# How can we sample from a large data in PySpark quickly when we don't the the size of dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two pyspark dataframe `tdf` and `fdf`, where `fdf` is extremely larger than `tdf`. And the sizes of these dataframes are changing daily, and I don't know them. I want to randomly pick data from `fdf` to compose a new dataframe `rdf`, where size of `rdf` is approximately equal to the size of `tdf`. Currently I have these lines:

```
tdf = tdf.count()
fdf = fdf.count()
sampling_fraction = float(tdf) / float(fdf)
rdf = fdf(sampling_fraction, SEED)
```

These lines produce correct result. But when the size of `fdf` is increasing, the `fdf.count()` takes a few days to finish. Can you suggest another approach that is faster in PySpark?

Comment: The answer you are looking for is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943769/how-do-i-get-the-row-count-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: My question was related to PySpark and not Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try sampling from the dataframe to get an estimated count:

```
ratio = 0.01
fdf_estimate = fdf.sample(fraction=ratio).count() / ratio
```

You can change the ratio to an appropriate value so that it gives a reasonable performance.