# Pandas - get count of each boolean field

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

I have other programs where I group and count fields. Now, I want to get a count of each boolean field. Is there a Pandas way to do that rather than me looping and writing my own code?  Ideally, I would generated a new dataframe with the results (kind of like what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66344545/simple-pandas-dataframe-read-csv-then-groupby-with-count-keyerror/66344565?noredirect=1#comment117291804_66344565)).

**Easy Example CSV Data (data about poker hands generated):**

```
Hand,Other1,Other2,IsFourOfAKind,IsThreeOfAKind,IsPair 
1,'a','b',1,0,0
2,'c','d',0,1,0
3,'a','b',0,1,0
4,'x','y',0,0,1
5,'a','b',0,0,1
6,'a','b',0,0,1
7,'a','b',0,0,1
```

**Program:**

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings 
filename = "./data/TestGroup2.csv"

# tell run time to ignore certain read_csv type errors (from pandas)
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message="^Columns.*")

count_cols = ['IsFourOfAKind','IsThreeOfAKind','IsPair ']
enter code here
#TODO - use the above to get counts of only these columns 

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
print(df.head(10))
```

**Desired Output - could just be a new dataframe**

```
 Column           Count 
IsFourOfAKind      1
IsThreeOfAKind     2
IsPair             3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
df.filter(like='Is').sum(0)
```

or did you need;

```
df1=df.filter(like='Is').agg('sum').reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'column', 0:'count'})
```

Comment: Second one - Wow, that is so cool.  I have many years of SQL, but so powerful what you can do with one command in Pandas!  I just like second, in case I need more control to loop, match to expected values, etc...