# Converting class 'pandas.core.series.Series' to "float"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm doing a training task in Jupyter notebook and I'm writing the following code to count the number of items in the "Trans_id" column of the table:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('Xyz.csv')
 num_trans = df["trans_id"].value_counts()
 num_trans
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> Your answer has the type `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` for the `num_trans` variable but we expected an `int` or  `float`. Double check your code.

I tried to solve it the following way but it didn't work:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('Xyz.csv')
 num_trans = df["trans_id"].value_counts()
 num_trans.to_float()
 num_trans
```

How would you recommend me to solve it? Thank you!!!

Comment: [How do I get the row count of a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15943975)

Comment: It isn't clear what you are expecting, `.value_counts()` returns another *series*. How exactly should a series, say, `pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).value_counts()` be converted to a `float`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close the question because it's not clear what you're looking for. It sounds like you want either the len of `df["trans_id"]` or the number of non-null items in it, but I'm not sure why the system would be expecting a float for that. You can [edit] to clarify. Please make a [mre], or as close as possible.

Comment: It seems, indeed that I need  the len of df["trans_id"], as I need to count the number of transactions in the table for marketing research and the number of transactions is in the end the number of rows (this is a cleaned sample and it doesn´t contain duplicate values). I first wanted to count only unique values that is why I tried value_counts and applied it to the column 'trans_id' with id numbers of transactions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: Misunderstood question earlier.

`num_trans` is a Series because .value_counts() returns a Series. Refer [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for reference.

However, if I understand correctly, you want to use it outside of pandas' that's why you are trying to make it a float. Instead of float, you should make it a `dict` !

EDIT2:
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74815999/converting-class-pandas-core-series-series-to-float#comment132043110_74815999) comment by OP, they want the count of unique values!
So, this is more suitable for the job:
`num_trans = len(df["trans_id"].unique())`

But if you insist on using `value_counts`, this will also work the same: `len(dict(df["trans_id"].value_counts()))`

Comment: this doesn't actually create any `int` or `float` objects. The OP seems to be using some automated grader, and it expects `num_trans` variable to have an object of the type `int` or `float`

Comment: Well, OP gotta tell us what they want to do with value_counts()'s output now, lol.