# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method error in scraping a help page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I created python script to scrape **facebook** *help page*. I wanted to scrape `cms_object_id`, `cmsID`, `name`. so these values are in a script tag then firstly tried to find all `<script>` tags then tried to iterate over this and then there is `__bbox` inside the tags which contains the values wanted to scrape.

so this is my script:

```
import json
import requests
import bs4
from Essentials import Static


class CmsIDs:
    def GetIDs():
        # cont = requests.get(""https://www.facebook.com:443/help"", headers=Static.headers) # syntax error
        cont = requests.get("https://www.facebook.com:443/help", headers=Static.headers)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(cont.content, "html5lib")

        text = soup.find_all("script")

        start = ""
        txtstr = ""

  

        for i in range(len(text)):
    
            mystr = text[i]

            # mystr = text[i]
            print("this is: ", mystr.find('__bbox":'))
            if text[i].get_text().find('__bbox":') != -1:
                # print(i, text[i].get_text())
                txtstr += text[i].get_text()
                start = text[i].get_text().find('__bbox":') + len('__bbox":')

        print('start:', start)

        count = 0
        for end, char in enumerate(txtstr[start:], start):
            if char == '{':
                count += 1
            if char == '}':
                count -= 1
            if count == 0:
                break
        print('end:', end)

        # --- convert JSON string to Python structure (dict/list) ---

        data = json.loads(txtstr[start:end+1])
        # pp.pprint(data)
        print('--- search ---')
        CmsIDs.search(data)

        # --- use recursion to find all 'cms_object_id', 'cmsID', 'name' ---

    def search(data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            found = False
            if 'cms_object_id' in data:
                print('cms_object_id', data['cms_object_id'])
                found = True
            if 'cmsID' in data:
                print('cmsID', data['cmsID'])
                found = True
            if 'name' in data:
                print('name', data['name'])
                found = True
            if found:
                print('---')
            for val in data.values():
                CmsIDs.search(val)
        if isinstance(data, list):
            for val in data:
                CmsIDs.search(val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CmsIDs.GetIDs()
```

the page contains `cms_object_id`, `cmsID`, `name`. so wanted to scrape all these 3 values but I am getting an error:

```
for end, char in enumerate(txtstr[start:], start):
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

so how can I solve this error and reach ultimate goal?

Comment: Well, what does `print('start:', start)` give you…?

Comment: @deceze it is empty and I don't know firstly working but not now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Since I'm unfamiliar with and failed to install `Essentials`, and also because *`""https://www.facebook.com:443/help""`* **raises a syntax error** (there should only be one quote on each side of the string), I changed the `requests` line in my code.

```py
        cont = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com:443/help', headers={'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'})
```

---

> ```py
> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
> ```

You've initiated `start` as a string [*`start = ""`*] and it needs to be an integer. Unless the *`if text[i].get_text().find('__bbox":') != -1....`* block is entered, `start` remains a string.

if you just want to not get this error, you could just exit the program if `start` hasn't been updated [indicating that `__bbox":` wasn't found in any of the `script` tags].

```py
        print('start:', start)
        if start == "":
            print('{__bbox":} not found')
            return

        count = 0
```

But that still leaves the problem of `__bbox":` not being found; I'm not sure *why*, but the issue is resolved for me if I don't use the `html5lib` parser - just changing to **`BeautifulSoup(cont.content)`** resolved *this* issue.

```py
        # soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(cont.content, "html5lib")
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(cont.content) # don't define the parser 
        # soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(cont.content, "html.parser") # you could also try other parsers
```

---

---

##### Other suggestions

Your code will probably work without these, but you might want to consider these suggested improvements for error-handling:

---

***Filter the `script` Tags***

If the `text` ResultSet only has `script` tags that contain `__bbox":`, you avoid looping unnecessarily through the 100+ other `script`s, and you won't have to check with `if....find('__bbox":')` anymore.

```py
        text = soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'script' and '"__bbox"' in t.get_text())

        for mystr in [s.get_text() for s in text]:
            print("this is: ", mystr.find('__bbox":'))
            txtstr += mystr
            start = mystr.find('__bbox":') + len('__bbox":')
```

---

***Initiate `end`***

You should initiate the `end` variable [like `end = 0`] before the *`for end, char ...`* loop because you're using it after the loop as well.

> ```py
>         print('end:', end)
> ```
>
> ```py
>         data = json.loads(txtstr[start:end+1])
> ```

If `txtstr[start:]` is empty somehow, these lines will raise error/s since `end` would not be defined yet.

---

***Use a JavaScript Parser***

This will make the previous suggestions unnecessary, but as it is `json.loads` will raise an error if `txtstr[start:end+1]` is empty somehow, or if it contains any unpaired [and likely escaped] `}`or`{`. So, it might be more reliable to use a parser rather than just trying to walk through the string.

I have [this function](https://pastebin.com/UVcLniSG) that uses [`slimit`](https://pypi.org/project/slimit/) to find values from strings containing JavaScript code. (It's far from perfect, but it seems to for this script, at least.) `GetIDs()` could be re-written as below.

```py
# import json, requests, bs4, slimit
# from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor 
# def findObj_inJS... ## PASTE FROM https://pastebin.com/UVcLniSG

# class CmsIDs:
    def GetIDs():
        # cont=requests.get('https://www.facebook.com:443/help',headers=Static.headers)
        cont = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com:443/help', headers={
            'accept': ';'.join(
                [ 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml',
                  'q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*',
                  'q=0.8,application/signed-exchange',
                  'v=b3', 'q=0.9'  ])})

        ## in case of request errors ##
        try: cont.raise_for_status()
        except Exception as e:
            print('failed to fetch page HTML -', type(e), e)
            return
        print('fetched', cont.url, 'with', cont.status_code, cont.reason)

        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(cont.content)
        scrCond = lambda t: t.name == 'script' and '"__bbox"' in t.get_text()
        jScripts = [s.get_text() for s in soup.find_all(scrCond)] 
        print(f'Found {len(jScripts)} script tags containing {{"__bbox"}}')

        data = [findObj_inJS(s,'"__bbox"') for s in jScripts]
        print('--- search ---')
        CmsIDs.search(data) 

    # def search(data)....
```

---

***Return the Data***

This isn't for error-handling, but if you return the data printed by `CmsIDs.search` you could save it for further use.

```py
    def search(data):
        rList, dKeys = [], ['cms_object_id', 'cmsID', 'name']
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            dObj = {k: data[k] for k in dKeys if k in data}
            rList += [dObj] if dObj else []

            for k, v in dObj.items(): print(k, v)
            if dObj: print('---')

            for val in data.values(): rList += CmsIDs.search(val)
        if isinstance(data, list):
            for val in data: rList += CmsIDs.search(val)
        return rList
```

The [printed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzO2v.png) will be the same as before, but if you **change the last line of `GetIDs`** to

```py
        return CmsIDs.search(data)
```

and then define a variable *`cmsList = CmsIDs.GetIDs()`* then `cmsList` will be a [list of dctionaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAknk.png), which you could then [for example] save to csv with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and view as a table on a spreadsheet.

```py
# import pandas
pandas.DataFrame(cmsList).to_csv('CmsIDs_GetIDs.csv', index=False)
```

or [print the markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8xh4.png) for the table [of the results I got] below

```py
print(pandas.DataFrame(cmsList, dtype=str).fillna('').to_markdown())
```

| [index] | cms_object_id | name | cmsID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | Використання Facebook |  |
| 1 | 570785306433644 | Створення облікового запису |  |
| 2 | 396528481579093 | Your Profile |  |
| 3 |  | Додати й редагувати інформацію у своєму профілі | 1017657581651994 |
| 4 |  | Ваші основна світлина й обкладинка | 1217373834962306 |
| 5 |  | Поширення дописів у своєму профілі та керування ними | 1640261589632787 |
| 6 |  | Усунення проблем | 191128814621591 |
| 7 | 1540345696275090 | Додавання в друзі |  |
| 8 |  | Додавання друзів | 246750422356731 |
| 9 |  | Люди, яких ви можете знати | 336320879782850 |
| 10 |  | Control Who Can Friend and Follow You | 273948399619967 |
| 11 |  | Upload Your Contacts to Facebook | 1041444532591371 |
| 12 |  | Видалення з друзів чи блокування користувача | 1000976436606344 |
| 13 | 312959615934334 | Facebook Dating |  |
| 14 | 753701661398957 | Ваша головна сторінка |  |
| 15 |  | How Feed Works | 1155510281178725 |
| 16 |  | Control What You See in Feed | 964154640320617 |
| 17 |  | Like and React to Posts | 1624177224568554 |
| 18 |  | Пошук | 821153694683665 |
| 19 |  | Translate Feed | 1195058957201487 |
| 20 |  | Memories | 1056848067697293 |
| 21 | 1071984682876123 | Повідомлення |  |
| 22 |  | Надсилання повідомлень | 487151698161671 |
| 23 |  | Переглянути повідомлення й керувати ними | 1117039378334299 |
| 24 |  | Поскаржитися на повідомлення | 968185709965912 |
| 25 |  | Відеовиклики | 287631408243374 |
| 26 |  | Fix a Problem | 1024559617598844 |
| 27 | 753046815962474 | Reels |  |
| 28 |  | Watching Reels | 475378724739085 |
| 29 |  | Creating Reels | 867690387846185 |
| 30 |  | Managing Your Reels | 590925116168623 |
| 31 | 862926927385914 | Розповіді |  |
| 32 |  | Як створити розповідь і поширити її | 126560554619115 |
| 33 |  | View and Reply to Stories | 349797465699432 |
| 34 |  | Page Stories | 425367811379971 |
| 35 | 1069521513115444 | Світлини й відео |  |
| 36 |  | Світлини | 1703757313215897 |
| 37 |  | Відео | 1738143323068602 |
| 38 |  | Going Live | 931327837299966 |
| 39 |  | Albums | 490693151131920 |
| 40 |  | Додавання позначок | 267689476916031 |
| 41 |  | Усунення проблеми | 507253956146325 |
| 42 | 1041553655923544 | Відео у Watch |  |
| 43 |  | Перегляд шоу та відео | 401287967326510 |
| 44 |  | Fix a Problem | 270093216665260 |
| 45 | 2402655169966967 | Gaming |  |
| 46 |  | Gaming on Facebook | 385894640264219 |
| 47 |  | Платежі в іграх | 248471068848455 |
| 48 | 282489752085908 | Сторінки |  |
| 49 |  | Interact with Pages | 1771297453117418 |
| 50 |  | Створити сторінку й керувати нею | 135275340210354 |
| 51 |  | Імена й імена користувачів | 1644118259243888 |
| 52 |  | Керування налаштуваннями сторінки | 1206330326045914 |
| 53 |  | Customize a Page | 1602483780062090 |
| 54 |  | Publishing | 1533298140275888 |
| 55 |  | Messaging | 994476827272050 |
| 56 |  | Insights | 794890670645072 |
| 57 |  | Banning and Moderation | 248844142141117 |
| 58 |  | Усунути проблему | 1020132651404616 |
| 59 | 1629740080681586 | Групи |  |
| 60 |  | Join and Choose Your Settings | 1210322209008185 |
| 61 |  | Post, Participate and Privacy | 530628541788770 |
| 62 |  | Create, Engage and Manage Settings | 408334464841405 |
| 63 |  | Керування групою для адміністраторів | 1686671141596230 |
| 64 |  | Community Chats | 3397387057158160 |
| 65 |  | Pages in Groups | 1769476376397128 |
| 66 |  | Fix a Problem | 1075368719167893 |
| 67 | 1076296042409786 | Події |  |
| 68 |  | Create and Manage an Event | 572885262883136 |
| 69 |  | View and Respond to Events | 1571121606521970 |
| 70 |  | Facebook Classes | 804063877226739 |
| 71 | 833144153745643 | Fundraisers and Donations |  |
| 72 |  | Creating a Fundraiser | 356680401435429 |
| 73 |  | Пожертва в рамках збору коштів | 1409509059114623 |
| 74 |  | Особисті збори коштів | 332739730519432 |
| 75 |  | For Nonprofits | 1640008462980459 |
| 76 |  | Fix a Problem | 2725517974129416 |
| 77 | 1434403039959381 | Meta Pay |  |
| 78 |  | Платежі в іграх | 248471068848455 |
| 79 |  | Payments in Messages | 863171203733904 |
| 80 |  | Пожертва в рамках збору коштів | 1409509059114623 |
| 81 |  | Квитки на заходи | 1769557403280350 |
| 82 |  | Monetization and Payouts | 1737820969853848 |
| 83 | 1713241952104830 | Marketplace |  |
| 84 |  | Як працює Marketplace | 1889067784738765 |
| 85 |  | Buying on Marketplace | 272975853291364 |
| 86 |  | Продаж на Marketplace | 153832041692242 |
| 87 |  | Sell with Shipping on Marketplace | 773379109714742 |
| 88 |  | Using Checkout on Facebook | 1411280809160810 |
| 89 |  | Групи з купівлі й продажу | 319768015124786 |
| 90 |  | Get Help with Marketplace | 1127970530677256 |
| 91 | 1642635852727373 | Додатки |  |
| 92 |  | Manage Your Apps | 942196655898243 |
| 93 |  | Видимість і конфіденційність додатка | 1727608884153160 |
| 94 | 866249956813928 | Додатки Facebook для мобільних пристроїв |  |
| 95 |  | Додаток для Android | 1639918076332350 |
| 96 |  | iPhone and iPad Apps | 1158027224227668 |
| 97 |  | Facebook Lite App | 795302980569545 |
| 98 | 273947702950567 | Спеціальні можливості |  |
| 99 |  | Керування обліковим записом |  |
| 100 | 1573156092981768 | Вхід і пароль |  |
| 101 |  | Вхід в обліковий запис | 1058033620955509 |
| 102 |  | Змінення пароля | 248976822124608 |
| 103 |  | Виправлення проблеми із входом | 283100488694834 |
| 104 |  | Завантаження посвідчення особи | 582999911881572 |
| 105 | 239070709801747 | Налаштування облікового запису |  |
| 106 |  | Як змінити налаштування облікового запису | 1221288724572426 |
| 107 |  | Ваше ім’я користувача | 1740158369563165 |
| 108 |  | Спадкоємці | 991335594313139 |
| 109 | 1090831264320592 | Імена у Facebook |  |
| 110 | 1036755649750898 | Сповіщення |  |
| 111 |  | Push, Email and Text Notifications | 530847210446227 |
| 112 |  | Виберіть, про що отримувати сповіщення | 269880466696699 |
| 113 |  | Усунення проблем | 1719980288275077 |
| 114 | 109378269482053 | Налаштування реклами |  |
| 115 |  | Як працює реклама у Facebook | 516147308587266 |
| 116 |  | Контроль реклами, яку ви бачите | 1075880512458213 |
| 117 |  | Ваша інформація та реклама у Facebook | 610457675797481 |
| 118 | 1701730696756992 | Доступ до вашої інформації та її завантаження |  |
| 119 | 250563911970368 | Деактивація або видалення облікового запису |  |
| 120 |  | Конфіденційність і безпека |  |
| 121 | 238318146535333 | Ваша конфіденційність |  |
| 122 |  | Керуйте тим, хто може переглядати контент, який ви поширюєте у Facebook | 1297502253597210 |
| 123 |  | Керування своїми дописами | 504765303045427 |
| 124 |  | Control Who Can Find You | 1718866941707011 |
| 125 | 592679377575472 | Безпека |  |
| 126 |  | Джерела щодо боротьби з жорстоким поводженням | 726709730764837 |
| 127 |  | Ресурси з допомоги для протидії самогубству та самоушкодженню | 1553737468262661 |
| 128 |  | Crisis Response | 141874516227713 |
| 129 |  | Ресурси з правил безпеки для допомоги батькам | 1079477105456277 |
| 130 |  | Інформація для правоохоронних органів | 764592980307837 |
| 131 | 235353253505947 | Захист облікового запису |  |
| 132 |  | Функції безпеки та поради з її забезпечення | 285695718429403 |
| 133 |  | Сповіщення про вхід і двоетапна перевірка | 909243165853369 |
| 134 |  | Уникайте спаму та шахрайства | 1584206335211143 |
| 135 | 236079651241697 | Безпека під час здійснення покупок |  |
| 136 |  | Розпізнавання шахрайства | 1086141928978559 |
| 137 |  | Уникнення шахрайства | 2374002556073992 |
| 138 |  | Купівля на Marketplace | 721562085854101 |
| 139 |  | Поради щодо безпечної купівлі | 123884166448529 |
| 140 |  | Купуйте впевнено | 1599248863596914 |
| 141 |  | Політики та скарги |  |
| 142 | 1753719584844061 | Скарга на порушення |  |
| 143 |  | Як поскаржитися на щось? | 1380418588640631 |
| 144 |  | Don't Have an Account? | 1723400564614772 |
| 145 | 1126628984024935 | Як повідомити про проблему у Facebook |  |
| 146 | 186614050293763 | Being Your Authentic Self on Facebook |  |
| 147 | 1561472897490627 | Повідомлення про порушення конфіденційності |  |
| 148 | 1216349518398524 | Зламані та фальшиві облікові записи |  |
| 149 | 275013292838654 | Керування обліковим записом померлої людини |  |
| 150 |  | About Memorialized Accounts | 1017717331640041 |
| 151 |  | Request to Memorialize or Remove an Account | 1111566045566400 |
| 152 | 399224883474207 | Інтелектуальна власність |  |
| 153 |  | Авторське право | 1020633957973118 |
| 154 |  | Торговельна марка | 507663689427413 |
| 155 | 1735443093393986 | Про наші політики |  |

Comment: Can you summarize this in one code pls.

Comment: @hanan the only corrections you MUST try to make the code work at all are to get fix the syntax error in `requests.get` and to get rid of the `"html5lib"` part, but this is the full code I ran to get the table: https://pastebin.com/Q4hrMHK6

Comment: thanks for the replies but `slimit` is causing me issues,  import slimit
  `File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\slimit\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from minifier import minify`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'minifier'` tried`pip install minifier` but  it seems no version is found.

Comment: forget about it. resolved this error.

Comment: in the dataFrame `cmsID` if I wanted to print the number of data contained, I'm getting some error. help me with this

Comment: @hanan what error are you getting? please include the line (or preferably a screenshot)

Comment: I was trying to save it in a `csv` file, this is the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`. how can I save this into `csv` file?

Comment: you're getting the error on the line with *`pandas.DataFrame(cmsList).to_csv('CmsIDs_GetIDs.csv', index=False)`*? may I see a screenshot?

Comment: That is correct. I was using wrongly that what caused to the error. thanks for correction though. and if I wanted to update the `CmsIDs_GetIDs.csv` with no duplicate values only added new values what can I do? Thanks

Comment: @hanan you can call `.to_csv` in append mode by passing **`mode='a'`** to not over-write previous file data (but keep in mind that if you don't set `header=False`, the header row will be repeated before the new rows), but if you want to avoid duplicates, you'll probably have to load the previous data to check against - if you need more details it'd be better to post another q. I can't fit more into comments, but maybe look into [`.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)&[`.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

Comment: tried to different approaches, still no luck. for example: `old_data = pandas.read_csv("./CmsIDs_GetIDs.csv")` `n= pandas.DataFrame(cmsList).to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
new_data = pandas.read_csv("./data.csv")` and then tried to compare each as: `old_data.compare(new_data)` but unfortunately I am getting an error : `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects` what can I do this to solve  this?

Comment: @hanan you can't `.compare` with a DataFrame that has a different length - they have to have the same shape, index and header. The error is likely due to `new_data` having more or less rows than `old_data`...you can try `old_data.merge(new_data, how='outer')`

Comment: but I also wanted to print the new row on the console.

Comment: you could add empty rows to the whichever is shorter before comparing the old and merged

Comment: well, they update their web but how can I know how much empty rows would I need in this case.

Comment: @hanan just check their [length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15943769/6146136) and get the difference. whichever is shorter add that many empty rows to it

Comment: I tried this : [shared On pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DwUuVNay)  but I still get same error `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects` please help with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251114/discussion-between-hanan-and-driftr95).

Comment: @hanan can you post a new question?

Comment: currently I am thinking about how can I structure the question.

Comment: and I feel it is hard though