# How do I count the number of rows in a dataframe located in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Dictionary name = `tum4`
Example of DataFrame name in 'tum4' dictionary: `ES0001`

1)How do I count the number of rows in all dataframes in 'tum4' dictionary?

2)How do I count the number of rows in a specific dataframe in 'tum4' dictionary?

I tried:

1)Haven't got a clue

2)`len(tum4['ES0001'])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the row count of a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943769/how-do-i-get-the-row-count-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

1. How do I count the number of rows in all dataframes in 'tum4' dictionary?

```
out = sum(df.shape[0] for df in tum4.values())

# or
out = sum(map(len, tum4.values()))
```

2. How do I count the number of rows in a specific dataframe in 'tum4'

```
out = tum4['specific_name'].shape[0]

# or
out = len(tum4['specific_name'])
```

Also refer to this classical [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943769/how-do-i-get-the-row-count-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you so much mozway, regarding 1) do you know how I can get a list of the row count of every dataframe in the tum4 dictionary?

Comment: This is basic python, you should read on list/dictionary comprehensions ;) I'd use `{k: len(df) for k, df in tum4.values()}`